# Function saves new record for room table instead of booking table (booking table has room_id as foreign key)

Tags: spring, entity-framework, spring-boot, jpa

Ive tried to save record for booking in the bookings table, but it does not create a record and instead adds a room for the room table which i do not want as the room table is not supposed to change, only records of bookings should be added into the bookings table with a foreign key room_id of the room that was booked.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Tbl_Bookings Entity

```
package com.sam.ResourceBookingMS.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Bookings")
public class Tbl_Bookings implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "booking_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public Integer getEmployee_id() {
        return employee_id;
    }
    public void setEmployee_id(Integer employee_id) {
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
    }
    public Integer getEquipment_id() {
        return equipment_id;
    }
    public void setEquipment_id(Integer equipment_id) {
        this.equipment_id = equipment_id;
    }


    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "time")
    private String time;

    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Integer employee_id;

    @Column(name = "equipment_id")
    private Integer equipment_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Tbl_Rooms thisroom;


    public Tbl_Rooms getThisroom() {
        return thisroom;
    }
    public void setThisroom(Tbl_Rooms thisroom) {
        this.thisroom = thisroom;
    }
    public Tbl_Bookings() {

    }
    public Tbl_Bookings(String type, String date, String time, Integer employee_id, Integer equipment_id) {
        this.type = type;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
        this.equipment_id = equipment_id;
    }

}
```

Tbl_Rooms Entity

```
package com.sam.ResourceBookingMS.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Rooms")
public class Tbl_Rooms implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "room_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }
    public void setCapacity(String capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private String capacity;

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Tbl_Bookings.class, mappedBy = "id", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Tbl_Bookings> bookings;

    public Set<Tbl_Bookings> getBookings() {
        return bookings;
    }
    public void setBookings(Set<Tbl_Bookings> bookings) {
        this.bookings = bookings;
    }
    public Tbl_Rooms() {

    }
    public Tbl_Rooms(String name, String capacity, String location, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.location = location;
        this.description = description;


    }

}
```

Controller

```
package com.sam.ResourceBookingMS;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sam.ResourceBookingMS.model.Tbl_Bookings;
import com.sam.ResourceBookingMS.model.Tbl_Rooms;

@RestController
public class BookRmController {
    @Autowired
    private TblBkRepository tbr;
    @Autowired
    private TblRmRepository trr;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bookRm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String sendData(@RequestBody Tbl_Bookings bk) {

        Tbl_Rooms rm = entityManager.getReference(Tbl_Rooms.class, 1);
        System.out.println(rm.getId());
        Tbl_Bookings booking = new Tbl_Bookings();
        booking.setDate(bk.getDate());
        booking.setType(bk.getType());
        booking.setTime(bk.getTime());

        Tbl_Rooms room = new Tbl_Rooms();
        room.setCapacity(rm.getCapacity());
        room.setDescription(rm.getDescription());
        room.setLocation(rm.getLocation());
        room.setName(rm.getName());

        Set<Tbl_Bookings> bookingOfRoom = new HashSet<Tbl_Bookings>();
        bookingOfRoom.add(booking);

        room.setBookings(bookingOfRoom);
        booking.setThisroom(room);

        trr.save(room);

        return "Confirmed";

    }
}
```

This is the json data being sent to the controller.

{"room_id":2,"date":"2019-07-26","time":"10:00am to 10:30am","type":"Room"}

Comment: Hello tan, You already have data for rooms and want to insert a record for booking in with room_id, or you want to insert data to the both the tables

Comment: @PatelRomil , I want to insert a record for booking with room_id

Comment: Okay, you can see controller with `/onetomanyPID` and change according to I have written in answer and let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mappedBy` in parent must be matched with a name defined in the child 
*(change `id` to `thisroom`)*

*case: "save Child with Parents ID" (might be above UseCase)*

For that, we have to request the Child Entity with Parent ID (see JSON request at the controller and set the Parent for that Child) and using Child Repository save the object instead of using parent repository.

*case: "save child-parent at same request"*

For that, we have to request the Parent Entity which has multiple children (for OneToMany) and using for setting the childerns

---

Parent

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Tbl_Bookings.class, mappedBy = "thisroom", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Tbl_Bookings> bookings;
```

Child

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "room_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Tbl_Rooms thisroom;
```

---

Parent-Child Relationship for referance

*Parent.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int parentId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Child> child = new ArrayList<Child>();
}
```

*Child.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int childId;
    private String account;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName = "parentId", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
public class RelationshipController {

    @Autowired ParentRepository parentRepository;
    @Autowired ChildRepository childRepository;

    //save Child with Parent at same 
    @PostMapping(value = "/onetomany")
    public String OneToMany(@RequestBody Parent parent)
    {
        for (Child child : parent.getChild()) {
            child.setParent(parent);
        }

        parent.setChild(parent.getChild());
        parentRepository.save(parent);
        return "saved";

        /*{
            "name":"Romil",
            "child":[
               {"account":"1"},
               {"account":"2"}
             ]
        }*/
    }

        //save Child with Parent's ID
        @PostMapping(value = "/onetomanyPID")
        public String OneToMany(@RequestBody Child child)
        {
            child.setParent(child.getParent());;
            childRepository.save(child);
            return "saved";

            /*{
                 "account":"3",
                  "parent":{
                      "parentId":"1",
                       "name":"Romil"
                   }
            }*/
        }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

*Controller*

```
 @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(@RequestBody Tbl_Bookings bookings)
    {
        bookings.setThisroom(bookings.getThisroom());
        tbr.save(bookings);
        return "Confirmed";
    }
```

---

*JSON*

```
{
    "thisroom":{
       "id":"1"
    },
    "date":"2019-07-26",
    "time":"10:00am to 10:30am",
    "type":"Room"
}
```

---

*Tbl_Bookings*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Bookings")
public class Tbl_Bookings implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "booking_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "room_id")
    private Tbl_Rooms thisroom;
}
```

---

*Tbl_Rooms*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Rooms")
public class Tbl_Rooms implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "room_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Tbl_Bookings.class, mappedBy = "thisroom", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tbl_Bookings> bookings = new ArrayList<Tbl_Bookings>();
}
```

Comment: Hey, ive tried your method, but in my database it still saves the foreign key room_id as null.

Comment: @samueltan please update the question with changes which you have done with the json input

Comment: Okay so in the RequestBody i am sending over json data for booking, which includes the following: date, time, type , room_id

Comment: But there is no field in Tbl_Bookings for room_id

Comment: i want to use the room_id passed over to save into the foreign key column "room_id" in Tbl_Bookings.

Comment: I understand, but please update the question with changes you have done provide the JSON (as I have in the controller) for more clarity it will be helpful

Comment: hi i have updated the question with the json at the bottom

Comment: hope to hear from you

Comment: Hello @samueltan, I have pasted your code in my machine and done some changes now it is working fine as per requirements. Please try with it and let me know

Comment: @samueltan, please accept the answer so that further readers can identify the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

There are two points you made mistakes.

*First*) You need to change `OneToMany` relation in `Tbl_Rooms` class as below:

```
 @OneToMany(targetEntity = Tbl_Bookings.class, mappedBy = "thisroom", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Tbl_Bookings> bookings;
```

The `mappedBy` attribute should be the class member of owner side.

*Second*) You create a new `Tbl_Rooms` instance in controller. So it is natural a new record would be created for rooms too.